# Как взаимодействовать с сервером?

Tags: javascript, php

Не давно начала изучать веб-разработку, делаю в данный момент пет проект (социальная сеть),
И на моменте авторизации при входе попала в тупик.
В общем есть база данных на MySQL там хранится логин, пароль и имя пользователя
Когда пользователь вводит логин и пароль то php скрипт на сервере ищет в базе данных строку с таким логином и паролем, и находит. И вот дальше не понятно, что делать

Для начала я хочу для начала хотя бы вывести приветствие с именем пользователя на сайт, как вариант у меня возникала идея отправлять с сервера имя пользователя с данной строки, которую он нашел и затем уже джава скрипт её вставляет в html файл, но мне кажется это по другому как-то делается. Скажите может что-то подучить или как это осуществляется вообще пожалуйста.
Вот код с авторизацией на php

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$errors = [];

$mysql = new mysqli("скрыто", "скрыто", "скрыто", "скрыто");
$check_user = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = '$email' AND 
`Password` = '$password'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_user)) {
$errors[] = 'Пользователь найден';
echo json_encode($errors);



} else {
$errors[] = 'НЕТ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ';
echo json_encode($errors);
}

$mysql->close();

?>
```

Технологии, которые я знаю 
html, css, scss 
JavaScript - Основы 
php - слабо знаю 
mySQL - слабо знаю 
SQL - знаю только - то что это язык запросов на базы данных и гуглю запросы

Comment: Почитайте для начала книги. Там всё напиасно. Не поленитесь потратить на прочтение/изучение хотя бы месяца два